# Grpc CompleteAsync

Tags: c#, grpc

I have a Duplex streaming call open to the server and I want to cancel it from the client before it completes. To do this I am calling *CompleteAsync()* on my *IClientStreamWriter* and once this task has been awaited I am calling Cancel on the cancellation token passed to my AsyncEnumerator.MoveNext. Something like below pseudo code. What I'm finding it quite often this results in an *RpcException* in the *MoveNext* with a status of Cancelled. However if I insert an await Task.Delay(200) wait between *CompleteAsync* and *clientCancelled.Cancel()* then the MoveNext completes normally. So it seems like the server then has time to process the CompleteAsync messages and end the call normally.

My question is what is the recommended practice here? Is it safe to just call *CompleteAsync* and not bother to use the cancellation token? If so then when would I use the cancellation token? I can imagine a scenario were CompleteAsync throws an error or somehow the server doesn't communicate back with the client that there are no more messages. Without the cancellation token we could end up leaking resources.

```
var clientCancelled = new CancellationTokenSource();

    while (await responseStream.MoveNext(clientCancelled.Token))
    {
        var message = responseStream.Current;
        DoSomething(message); 
    }
```

Called when Client Cancels Request

```
await requestStream.CompleteAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
clientCancelled.Cancel()
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be related:
https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/16441

The last comment seems to kind of answer your question:

> cancelling the ResponseStream.MoveNext() is equivalent to cancelling the entire call and will result in getting a non-ok call's StatusCode.
>
> under normal circumstances, you should let your calls finish gracefully (i.e. call CompleteAsync() on the client to half close and return from the handler on the serverside). Then no exceptions will be thrown. Only use Cancel() if you actually want to cancel a call.

So in short you should not use Cancel() here.